# Failing sending mail: Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error.Mail will not be resent

Tags: reporting-services, subscriptions

I am using SharePoint to schedule subscriptions for SSRS reports. I have one report that has roughly 40 subscriptions and has been working perfectly for 6 months up until last week. Last week all of the subscriptions had a result of:

**Failing sending mail: Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error.Mail will not be resent.**

Since then I can create a new subscription to the same people OK but the subscription has never started again (it is a daily report). Is there anyway to reset the status of these reports or do I have to manually recreate all of the subscriptions?

Thank you